# multiple field search using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, search, stored-procedures

I have 24 fields in my table all of them are of nvarchar type except one of int type which is ID now I want to search in all fields for any text written by the user in textBox for example if the user will write "20" in the textBox it then should show all records that their fields have "20" .. I've written a stored procedure but it is not working whenever I write any thing that is existing in the fields of my table it doesn't return any thing in the data grid view !!
This is my stored procedure:

```
create proc searchClientProfile
@search nvarchar(255)
as
select * from clientProfile where convert(nvarchar,ID)+compName+Addres+compPhone+compEmail+compWebsite+shipAddress+shipPhone+primeContact+primePhone+primeEmail+secContact+secPhone+secEmail+sector+established+industry+anulPrch+country+region+town+stat+city+zip like '%@search%'
```

And this is the code in my textBox TextChanged event:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("searchClientProfile", cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter[] parm = new SqlParameter[1];
parm[0] = new SqlParameter("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
parm[0].Value = searchClientTxt.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parm);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(getSearchedClientProfiles);
searchClientsDgv.DataSource = getSearchedClientProfiles;
```

Comment: if one of the columns is null, the whole concartenation result is null. compare `select 'test'+null` against `select 'test'+ISNULL(null,'')`

Comment: You need to read this article and rethink your search logic. And definitely don't select *, only select the columns you need. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ And please note that using leading wildcard searches renders indexes useless. So doing this across all those columns is going to be horrible for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (clearly not sargable).

**Note:** an ALIAS is required.

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From clientProfil A
 Where (Select A.* for XML Raw) like '%'+@search+'%'
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Not seen this approach before.

Comment: @SeanLange Just some lazy coding where performance is not paramount.

Comment: Yeah I can see where the performance would be a bit questionable but also a cool trick for some down and dirty research. I could see an easy modification to this for the "search every field of every table to find x".

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Nice and quick approach. How about if performance is important. In that case how to search a string in each of the columns returned in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly you want to check if a column of of your 20 contains your search query. It should look something like that :

```
select * 
from clientProfile 
where convert(nvarchar,ID) like '%@search%'
OR compName like '% ' + @search + '%'
OR Addres like '%'+@search + '%'
OR compPhone like '%'+@search + '%'
OR compEmail like '%'+@search + '%'
OR compWebsite like '%'+@search + '%'
OR shipAddress like '%'+@search + '%'
OR shipPhone like '%'+@search + '%'
OR primeContact like '%'+@search + '%'
OR primePhone like '%'+@search + '%'
OR primeEmail like '%'+@search + '%'
OR secContact like '%'+@search + '%'
OR secPhone like '%'+@search + '%'
OR secEmail like '%'+@search + '%'
OR sector like '%'+@search + '%'
OR established like '%'+@search + '%'
OR industry like '%'+@search + '%'
OR anulPrch like '%'+@search + '%'
OR country like '%'+@search + '%'
OR region like '%'+@search + '%'
OR town like '%'+@search + '%'
OR stat like '%'+@search + '%'
OR city like '%'+@search + '%'
OR zip like '%'+@search + '%'
```

I don't know how you built your application but the performances will not be amazing on that kind a query

Answer (score 0):

In concatenation, you should handle `NULL` values. It can be done using `ISNULL` or `CONCAT`.

Also, what if in `ecContact` and `secPhone` you have `sea` and `rch` correspondingly? You will concatenate them as `search` and have a match. You need to use a separator.

If I were you, I will just write the condition check for column.

```
create proc searchClientProfile
' + @search + ' nvarchar(255)
as
select * from clientProfile where convert(nvarchar,ID) like '%' + @search + '%' OR compName like '%' + @search + '%' OR Addres like '%' + @search + '%' OR compPhone like '%' + @search + '%' OR compEmail like '%' + @search + '%' OR compWebsite like '%' + @search + '%' OR shipAddress like '%' + @search + '%' OR shipPhone like '%' + @search + '%' OR primeContact like '%' + @search + '%' OR primePhone like '%' + @search + '%' OR primeEmail like '%' + @search + '%' OR secContact like '%' + @search + '%' OR secPhone like '%' + @search + '%' OR secEmail like '%' + @search + '%' OR sector like '%' + @search + '%' OR established like '%' + @search + '%' OR industry like '%' + @search + '%' OR anulPrch like '%' + @search + '%' OR country like '%' + @search + '%' OR region like '%' + @search + '%' OR town like '%' + @search + '%' OR stat like '%' + @search + '%' OR city like '%' + @search + '%' OR zip like '%' + @search + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for help guys ... Form the answers seen I altered my stored procedure specially the like part from '%@search%' to '%'+@search+'%' second in my C# code I've added to TextChanged event a line of code that clears the previous content of data grid view so now the code of TextChanged event looks like:

```
getSearchedClientProfiles.Clear();
cmd = new SqlCommand("searchClientProfile", cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter[] parm = new SqlParameter[1];
parm[0] = new SqlParameter("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
parm[0].Value = searchClientTxt.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parm);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(getSearchedClientProfiles);
searchClientsDgv.DataSource = getSearchedClientProfiles;
```